# Access sqlite in server through client side javascript

Tags: javascript, python, sql, sqlite

I have sqlite db runing on my server. I want to access it using client side javascript in browser. Is this possible?

As of now, I am using python to access the db and calling python scripts for db operations.

Comment: JavaScript <=> Ajax <=> Web service/API implemented in python <=> DB

Comment: Exactly! I have been using Ajax. Just wondering if there's another way using javascript in browser.

Comment: It is a bad idea to allow a client side script (which can be modified by a user) to directly access a database and allow to send statements to it. This allows to arbitrarily modify the database or to run complex calculations on your server.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to allow clients to access directly to the db. If you have to do it be carefull to not give to the account you use full write/read access to the db or any malicius client can erase modify or steal information from the db.

An implementation with client identification server-side and rest API to return or modify DB it's safer.

Comment: I completely agree about the fact that we should use a backend implementation for db related operations. I was just curious of how to do it in client side, if at all I want to do it